# Microsoft graph: get only users from group

Tags: odata, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Just wondering if there's any way to get only the users placed inside an azure ad group. I've tried something like this:

```
var membros = await obtemUtilizadores
                .Filter("'odata.type' eq '#microsoft.graph.user'")
                .Select("id,userprincipalname,mail,displayname")
                .Expand("extensions($filter=id eq 'assistenciasExtensions')")
                .GetAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

It translates into this url:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/xxxxxx/members?
 $filter='odatatype eq 'microsoft.graph.user'&
 $select=id,userprincipalname,mail,displayname&
 $expand=extensions($filter=id eq 'assistenciasExtensions')
```

Which returns an error saying that the filter is wrong.

Btw, what I really need is to get all users from within group X with the assistenciasExtensions data.

Thanks.

Luis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately a service-side filter for this is not currently possible (filtering on the target of a navigation collection - for type and/or any property including extension properties).  You'll need to get all members and then filter on the client side.  Appreciate that this is pretty awful - I filed a user voice item for this - please feel free to vote for this feature.  https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/19587061-allow-filter-on-target-of-a-navigation-collection

Hope this helps,

Comment: Hello Dan. The worst part is that probably means I'll have to make n extra calls (where n equals all loaded users) because only users have the assistenciasExtensions extension, right?