# Is it possible to list only organizational contacts from a group with Azure AD Graph Api?

Tags: azure, outlook, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm using Azure ActiveDirectory Graph API. I can list members(users,contacts,other groups) of a group. I noticed, when I add in office.outlook.com a contact (not personal, organizational contact) to a group, it will be a guest user (add a user, it will be a user ofc). When I list members of a group, I get a list of user objects. I got the guest users and the normal users too. I didn't find any solution for that, to list only the contacts (guest users) from a group. My question is, is this possible?

I use this in my code:
          `https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/groups/{object_id}/members?api-version`

Answer (score 2):

If you check the response , you will find `userType` property in `Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User` . `userType` is a string value that can be used to classify user types in your directory, such as "Member" and "Guest".

Unfortunately a service-side filter for this is not currently possible (filtering on the target of a navigation collection - for type and/or any property including extension properties). See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44535436) . And you could [vote for this feature](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/19587061-allow-filter-on-target-of-a-navigation-collection).

Currently you will need to get all members and then filter on the client side , find the guest users that  `userType` value equals `Guest` .